# jQuery addClass/removeClass only working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can anyone tell me why this would work in Firefox but not Safari or Chrome?

The `newClass` variable just gets the input from a select box value and I then use that to create a selector and use `addClass`/`removeClass` on that selected element.

I tried different syntax such as adding the `.` into the variable rather than adding it within the selector but the result is the same.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.first_place_selection').click(function() {
    var newClass = $('#first_place').find(':selected').text();

    $("." + newClass).removeClass('second-active');
    $("." + newClass).removeClass('third-active');
    $("." + newClass).addClass('first-active');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="first_place" name="first_place" autocomplete="off" required>
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option class="first_place_selection" value="team1">team1</option>
  <option class="first_place_selection" value="team2">team2</option>
  <option class="first_place_selection" value="team3">team3</option>
  <option class="first_place_selection" value="team4">team4</option>
</select>

<div class="entry-number team1">1</div>
<div class="entry-number team2">2</div>
<div class="entry-number team3">3</div>
<div class="entry-number team4">4</div>
```

Comment: Provide a working demo.

Comment: This is pretty generic and would work in all browsers. My guess is you have other code running before it that's breaking in safari/chrome.

Comment: Have you tried replace "click" to "change"?

Comment: What do you try to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of click try change event while using select dropdown.

```
$('#first_place').change(function(){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $(this).removeClass('second-active third-active').addClass('first-active');
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried using change instead of click but then it stops working in ALL browsers

Comment: Thanks. Didn't quite do what I wanted but it put me on the track and I now have it working.